# At what point of processing are interceptors in gRCP executed?

Tags: grpc

When a server unary interceptor executes, has the gRCP library verified at that point that the method being called actually exists? We record metrics by method name and this should be a low cardinality dimension. What I'd like to know is if there's any possibility in which case the interceptor would execute on a call to a method which doesn't exist? This could cause an attacker to spam the metrics backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server call does [method lookup](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/2bec8cdf1d1059f2ef219fb33fd5559029de98f8/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/ServerImpl.java#L537C13-L537C13) first, if not found, it returns IMPLEMENTED: method not found. Then it does server interceptor [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/2bec8cdf1d1059f2ef219fb33fd5559029de98f8/core/src/main/java/io/grpc/internal/ServerImpl.java#L555)